# Index only displays 3 first fields, how to add more fields to the index?

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to add more fields to this index:

[image]

As you can see, in the image it only gives me the option of: ID, Processed_Date and Date.

But I want to select: Date, From, Subject, To_Recipients and body.

How can I add those fields to the dropdow in index creation?

Comment: Access doesn't offer **Long Text** columns in the Index window. In general, indexing a Long Text column is rarely useful, and can lead to problems, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42945057/ms-access-error-updating-memo-field-with-long-text

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MS Access Error updating memo field with long text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42945057/ms-access-error-updating-memo-field-with-long-text)